# Vim: sourcing based on a string

Tags: vim

I can't seem to find an answer to this in any of the numerous Vim scripting tutorials online.  What I want to do is construct a file name of a script from environment variables and then source it.  And I want to do it in Vim.

If I were to do it in a shell I'd do something like this:

```
source ${HOME}/.vim/myscript_${FOO}.vim
```

How do I do it in Vim?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can build up a string and then use the execute command:

```sh
exec "source " . $HOME . "/.vim/myscript_" . l:foo . ".vim"
```

(The `l:foo` here is an example of using a local variable from within a function.)

---

#### Edit:

But in fact `exec` is overkill in this specific case.  As rampion [shows here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840900/vim-sourcing-based-on-a-string/841025#841163), the OPs task can be done directly with:

```
source $HOME/.vim/myscript_$FOO.vim
```

Although vim does not let us wrap the variable names neatly in `${...}` like we could in the shell, in this case we are lucky that `HOME` is terminated by the `/` and `FOO` by the `.`

In general, `exec` *would* be needed if you wanted to follow one of the variables by a non-terminating character.  For example:

```sh
exec "source " . $BAR . "_script.vim"
```

would insert the `BAR` variable, while the following would try to find a variable called `BAR_script`:

```
source $BAR_script.vim       " Possibly not what you wanted!
```

#### Use shellescape() for safety

When adding a variable to a string to be executed, we should really use `shellescape()` to escape strange chars (for example spaces in filenames).

For example, these are safer versions of the above:

```
exec "source " . shellescape($HOME . "/.vim/myscript_" . l:foo) . ".vim"

exec "source " . shellescape($BAR) . "_script.vim"
```

Comment: Note: `shellescape()` can potentially add quotes around your string, which may cause the other command to fail. For instance, this fails for me: `exec 'source ' . shellescape(expand('<sfile>:p:h') . '/vimrc.local')` But it works fine if I remove the escaping function.

Answer (score 4):

Just `:source` works for me:

```
% export MYPATH='a/b/c'
% mkdir -p $MYPATH
% export MYFILE='temp.vim'
% cat > $MYPATH/$MYFILE
echo 'hello world'
^D
% vim
:source $MYPATH/$MYFILE
hello world
```

If you want to have some vim scripts automatically sourced though, just stick them in your `~/.vim/plugin/` directory, and they'll be loaded for you, without having to do it manually.

From `:help expand-environment-var` (which I got by doing `:help environment` and tab completing to the first likely result)

```
             *:set_env* *expand-env* *expand-environment-var*
    Environment variables in specific string options will be expanded.  If the
    environment variable exists the '$' and the following environment variable
    name is replaced with its value.  If it does not exist the '$' and the name
    are not modified.  Any non-id character (not a letter, digit or '_') may
    follow the environment variable name.  That character and what follows is
    appended to the value of the environment variable.  Examples: >
       :set term=$TERM.new
       :set path=/usr/$INCLUDE,$HOME/include,.
    When adding or removing a string from an option with ":set opt-=val" or ":set
    opt+=val" the expansion is done before the adding or removing.
```

I tend to find vim's built in help more useful than anything else, but it does take a while to get the knack of knowing what to look for.

Comment: Yes, I know that works, but your script path differs in a very specific way; you don't concatenate anything to your environment variables!

Comment: (+1)  Although Magnus originally said "environment variables" I thought he meant "vim variables".  rampion's solution does work for me with environment variables and concatenation.  :source $HOME/.vim/myscript_$FOO.vim

Comment: You could always store the vim variables in environment variables, if you wanted to be sneaky.