# How to concatenate environmental variables in a vimrc file

Tags: vim

I am trying to do something pretty simple in my vimrc style. As you can see below I am trying to concat two environmental variables into a local variable and then use that variable.

```
  let cs=$menv_dotfiles_dir."/vimrc_style/".${CODING_STYLE}.".vim"                
  if filereadable(cs)                                                             
    source cs                                                                     
  endif
```

Of course the above doesn't work but I think it expresses what I need to do. What is the correct way to do this?

Similar to this: [Vim: sourcing based on a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840900/vim-sourcing-based-on-a-string) But I need to do it only if the file exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were very close the `{}` brackets do not work like they do in bash.  You have to use `exec` if you want source from a string variable.

This works:

```
let cs=$menv_dotfiles_dir."/vimrc_style/".$CODING_STYLE.".vim"                
if filereadable(cs)                                                             
    exec 'source ' . cs                                                                     
endif
```